# Having issue with running python script having pytesseract library from maven project

Tags: python, java, maven, opencv, python-tesseract

I wanted to run a python script from my Java Maven project. Simple python scripts works fine without any issues.
But if i try something complicated like using OpenCV and pytesseract libraries to do some image recognition related tasks the code doesn't work.

The python script works fine if i just run it from the terminal (i have installed all the required libraries)
But the same script when called from the Java Maven project, it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
String path = "/Users/team/Desktop/my.py";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python3","/Users/team/Desktop/my.py").inheritIO();

Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();

BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = "";

while ((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

It is throwing below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/team/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 252, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tesseract'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/team/Desktop/my.py", line 73, in <module>
    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(src_path + "thres.png"))
  File "/Users/team/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 413, in image_to_string
    return {
  File "/Users/team/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 416, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "/Users/team/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 284, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/team/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 256, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractNotFoundError()
```

Could someone please help me figure this out please? I feel like the issue is because of some sort of PATH, but not sure how to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind trying using -Djava.library.path= so the java process knows where to locate the tesseract library.